# SQL query to separate a column into separate columns

Tags: sql, dataframe

I would like to have separate columns for H and T's prices, with 'period' as the common index. Any suggestions as to how I should go about this?

This is what my SQL query produces at the moment:

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and a conditional, like this:

```
SELECT
    period
,   SUM(CASE NAME WHEN 'H' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as HPrice
,   SUM(CASE NAME WHEN 'T' THEN price ELSE 0 END) as TPrice
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY period
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT period, 
    max(CASE WHEN name = 'H' THEN price END) as h_price,
    max(CASE WHEN name = 'T' THEN price END) as t_price
FROM myTable
GROUP by period
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to recreate the table?

1) Create a new table with columns: period, price_h & price_t.

2) Copy all (distinct) from period into new table's period.

3) Copy all price where name = H to new table's price_h joining the period column

4) repeat 3 for price_t....

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game on this but you could also pivot the data.

Lets create a sample table.

```
CREATE TABLE myData(period int, price decimal(12,4), name varchar(10))
GO
-- Inserting Data into Table

INSERT INTO myData
(period, price, name)
VALUES
(1, 53.0450, 'H'),
(1, 55.7445, 'T'),
(2, 61.2827, 'H'),
(2, 66.0544, 'T'),
(3, 61.3405, 'H'),
(3, 66.0327, 'T');
```

Now the select with the pivot performed.

```
SELECT period, H, T
FROM (
SELECT period, price, name
FROM myData) d
PIVOT (SUM(price) FOR name IN (H, T)) AS pvt
ORDER BY period
```

I've used this technique when I needed to build a dynamic sql script that took in the columns in which would be displayed on the header of the table.  No need for case statements.

Im not sure about the performance of the case and pivot.  Maybe someone with a little more experience could add some comments on which would give better performance.